# Storing passwords in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, security

There are many questions on SO about how to store passwords in a database and i'm aware passwords should under no circumstances be stored in plain text. However, my application requires authentication against various third parties, such as SMB or REST APIs that don't provide OAUTH. In short: i need to store passwords.

To avoid storing passwords in clear text, my idea is to store a secret key in an environment variable and use that for encrypting / decrypting the passwords.

Is that a good approach for the problem or are there any better options?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the attr_encrypted gem for transparently encrypting and decrypting attributes. This will let you write to a virtual attribute and upon save will seamlessly handle encrypting the data and persisting it into the database so that they are never stored as plain text.

Make sure to use the gem with the new default mode of :per_attribute_iv which will persist both the encrypted cipher text and individual IV for each encrypted attribute you want to store.

https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted